# What is the largest order of any element in $U_{900}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the largest order of any element in $U_{900}$?
I found that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z _{240}$. So I guess that it should be $240$. Am I correct?

Comment: $U_{900}$ does have 240 elements, but it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z _{240}$

Comment: How can you be sure about  this? Actually I have wrong idea, so I want to clear it .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You first factorise $900 = 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 2^2$. Then you determine the maximal order in $U_9$, in $U_{25}$ and in $U_4$ (you should already know the general structure of the groups for prime powers). Finally, the Chinese remainder theorem tells you that $U_{900}$ is the product of these three groups, so the maximal order in $U_{900}$ is the least common multiple of the maximal orders in the three components.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ The CRT decomposition is $\rm\ \Bbb Z/900 = \Bbb Z/4 \times \Bbb Z/9 \times \Bbb Z/25\ $ so $\rm\: U_{900} = U_{4}\times U_9\times U_{25},\ $ a product of cyclic groups of order $\rm\ \phi(4)=2,\ \phi(9)=6,\ \phi(25)=20,\:$ with lcm $= 60,\:$ not $240$. This implies $\rm\:a^{60} = 1\:$ for all $\rm\:a\in U_{900}.\:$ Indeed, if $\rm\:(a,b,c)\in C(i) \times C(j) \times C(k),\:$ a product of cyclic groups of order $\rm\:i,j,k,\:$ then

$$\rm  \ell = lcm(i,j,k)\mid n\:\Rightarrow\: i,j,k\mid n\:\Rightarrow\:(a,b,c)^n = (a^n,b^n,c^n) = 1$$

So the largest order $\rm\:\color{#c00}{m \le \ell}.\:$ Conversely, taking $\rm\:a,b,c\:$ to be generators

$$\rm\ 1 = (a,b,c)^n = (a^n,b^n,c^n) \:\Rightarrow\: i,j,k\mid n\:\Rightarrow\ \ell = lcm(i,j,k)\mid n$$

Thus $\rm\: \ell\le m.\:$ Combining $\rm\: \color{#c00}{m \le \ell} \le m,\:$ hence $\rm\:m = \ell.$

**Remark** $\ $ Look up the [Carmichael lambda function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) to learn more about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

That's the largest possible order, but that doesn't mean that there must exist an element with such an order. I ran a Python script and could not find any.

```
for i in range(900):
    if gcd(900, i) == 1:
        order = 1
        total = i
        while total != 1:
            total = (total * i) % 900
            order += 1
        if order == 240:
            print(i)
```

EDIT: Today I learned you need <pre> tags.

Comment: There's a "code" button which will put four spaces before each line of code.  This is interpreted in the same way.

Comment: Did you compute the largest order of any element? Otherwise, this would be a comment, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html)

$\lambda(900)=$lcm$(\phi(2^2),\phi(3^2),\phi(5^2))=$lcm$(2,6,20)=60$